# Double for Loop Using 2 Lists Compared to Double Loop Using 2 Text Files - Different Outcome

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, with-statement

So I have 2 mini scripts. 1 produces the output I expect, the other does not. First code that produces the output I expected:

```
with open('cities.txt', 'r') as cities, \
    open('test_file.txt', 'r') as test:
    space = " "
    city_lst = []
    test_lst = []
    for c in cities:
        city_lst.append(c)
    for t in test:
        test_lst.append(t)
    for city in city_lst:
        for tes in test_lst:
            print city.rstrip(),space,tes.rstrip()
```

Output (as I expected):

```
san diego   san diego is the best place
san diego   Then there is new york state
san diego   And now we have tuscon in arizona
san francisco   san diego is the best place
san francisco   Then there is new york state
san francisco   And now we have tuscon in arizona
tuscon   san diego is the best place
tuscon   Then there is new york state
tuscon   And now we have tuscon in arizona
pheonix   san diego is the best place
pheonix   Then there is new york state
pheonix   And now we have tuscon in arizona
sedona   san diego is the best place
sedona   Then there is new york state
sedona   And now we have tuscon in arizona
baton rouge   san diego is the best place
baton rouge   Then there is new york state
baton rouge   And now we have tuscon in arizona
```

In the next piece of code I didn't get the output I though I would. It is basically the same code as above, except that I am working directly with the text files and not converting them to lists first. However, It puzzles me why I don't get the exact same output.

The code:

```
with open('cities.txt', 'r') as cities, \
    open('test_file.txt', 'r') as test:
    space = " "
    for c in cities:
        for t in test:
            print c.rstrip(), space, t.rstrip()
```

Output:

```
san diego   san diego is the best place
san diego   Then there is new york state
san diego   And now we have tuscon in arizona
```

Since I am doing the same double for loop in each code, with the same print statement, why is that there is a difference in output?

Here is the content of the text files:
cities.txt:

```
san diego
san francisco
tuscon
pheonix
sedona
baton rouge
```

test_file.txt:

```
san diego is the best place
Then there is new york state
And now we have tuscon in arizona
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because file's objects are iterators. To convert it into list, use `.readlines()` function. Your code should be like:

```
with open('cities.txt') as cities, open('tests.txt') as tests:
    for c in cities.readlines()
        for t in tests.readlines():
            print(c.rstrip() + " " + t.rstrip())
```

Alternatively, you may also use `itertools.product()` to prevent nested loops. In that case, your code should be like:

```
with open('cities.txt') as cities, open('tests.txt') as tests:
    for c, t in itertools.product(cities.readlines(), tests.readlines()):
        print("{city} {test}".format(city=c,test=t))
```

Note: Instead of direct appending of string using `+`. It is better way to use `.format()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Because files are iterators, and lists are, well, lists.

When you do

```
for t in test:
    pass # do anything here
```

by the end of that loop you have EXHAUSTED your iterator. There's nothing more in it! Try it yourself!:

```
with open('testfile.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        print("There's a line here, I'm reading!")
    for line in inf:
        print("Turn lead into gold")
```

You'll notice a complete lack of alchemy here.

What you CAN do is to `seek` back to the beginning of the file before reading it each time.

```
for c in cities:
    test.seek(0)
    # place the pointer at the beginning of the file
    for t in test:
        frobnicate_stuff()
```

However I'd prefer reading each file once and operating on lists, as you do in the above example. You could probably do better with an [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

with open('cities.txt') as cities, \
         open('test.txt') as test:
    city_lst = cities.readlines()
    test_lst = test.readlines()

for c, t in itertools.product(city_lst, test_lst):
    print(c.rstrip() + " " + t.rstrip())
    # or using string formatting:
    # # print("{} {}".format(c.rstrip(), t.rstrip()))
```

***EDIT***

In fact, further testing shows that [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) internalizes each iterator before using it! This means that we can do:

```
with open('cities.txt') as cities, \
        open('tests.txt') as tests:
    for c, t in itertools.product(cities, tests):
        print(c.rstrip() + " " + t.rstrip())
```

Comment: `file.seek(0)` to "reset" the iterator in this special case. Well, `inf.seek(0)` here...

Comment: FGITW edit. Shoulda known. I'm gonna be using that `itertools.product` recipe!